# table-striped not working with Bootstrap SASS (even with the w3 school table)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I was working on a table when I tried to add the table-striped class (http://getBootstrap.com/css/#tables) to my table. Unfortunately it is not working. First, I tried it with my own table (code below) and after that the W3 Bootstrap 3 table code what is also not working.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Pakket naam</th>
             <th>Aantal vragen</th>
             <th>Bewerken</th>
             <th>Verwijder</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>A1 Poster</td>
             <td>5</td>
             <td><a href="#">Klik hier</a></td>
             <td><a href="#">Klik hier</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>A3 Poster</td>
             <td>20</td>
             <td><a href="#">Klik hier</a></td>
             <td><a href="#">Klik hier</a></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

I am using Bootstrap-SASS, and I am sure the `.table-striped` class is included in my stylesheet. What am I doing wrong? is it the table syntax what is wrong? Please help me out!

Comment: can you please provide fiddle where we can see issue as you mentioned sass so it will be great to have fiddle with your issue. ty

Comment: see here its ok for me https://jsfiddle.net/savkdmj1/

Comment: check if bootstrap stylesheet is working. check it's path

Comment: table-striped work in your jsfiddle, i found:     .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

Comment: Thanks all, I had `th, td {
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
}` in my code, not realising its overwritting the bootstrap code.. Silly me.. Thanks for the tip of jsfiddle, It made me realize this! :)